# How to pass the tick value on to the tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bar chart with a time scale along X axis.

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(RU.timeFormat("%b %Y"));
```

I need to pass these time values on to the tooltips for every bar. Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/anton9ov/L9bkeypo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the tick value like this:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
    //here i is the index of the bar
    //selecting the text with the index    
    var tickValue = d3.select(d3.selectAll(".axis .tick text")[0][i]).text();
```

Display in the tooltip like this:

```
d3.select("#tooltip" )
    .style("left" , xPosition + "px")
  .style("top" , yPosition + "px")
  .select("#label")
  .text(tickValue);
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/59q8q22s/)

Comment: One more question: is whether exists the way to replace the short names of month to the full names in the tooltip? I.e. "Jan" to "January", "Feb" to "February" and so on. But along the axis short names have to remain.

Comment: Yes like this:
`var tickDate = d3.select(d3.selectAll(".axis .tick text")[0][i]).data()[0];` This will give you the date associated to the tick. check the console in here https://jsfiddle.net/m68wv8z9/

Comment: Sorry for my importunity. Everything is working perfect now, but I can't understand what exactly occurs in this part of the code line: `d3.selectAll(".axis .tick text")[0][i]` D3 makes the selection with all the texts along the axis and... what's going on after that? What exactly the `[0][i]` combination does? I've not managed with finding answer via google. Could you explain me? One more sorry for a lot of questions, I'm new in D3

Comment: [0][i] in this we know `d3.selectAll(".axis .tick text")` will return an array of selection. So we get the first array of  selection `d3.selectAll(".axis .tick text")[0]` it will return an array of text inside the selection. In this `d3.selectAll(".axis .tick text")[0][i]` get the i'th index of the element from the array. Hope this clarifies it. Please shoot your new queries in case you have doubts, happy to help!